# CompositionalLayout Item Customization

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to setup separate CompositionalLayout items. I added example images as an attachment. How can I do this? Thanks.

[example image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aizr1.png) [example image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUQN9.png)

My CompositionalLayout Swift File:

```
 static func createCollectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let classicItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                           heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    )
    
    classicItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize:
        NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(2/5)),
                               subitem: classicItem,
       count: 2
    )
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your second screenshot, you have two different sections and you want to lay them out in two different ways. You are finding that you can't do it. The problem is that you're calling the wrong UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout initializer. You are calling this one:

[`init(section: NSCollectionLayoutSection)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout/3199211-init)

You want to call this one:

[`init(sectionProvider: @escaping UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutSectionProvider)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout/3199214-init)

That will allow you to add a *section provider* function that configures your layout differently depending on which section this is.